# How to insert documents with variable number of properties and variable property name into elasticsearch in C# using NEST

Tags: c#, dynamic, elasticsearch, nest

Normal way of inserting a document into Elastic Search in C# using NEST is to define a class with known properties where the property names and their attributes are fixed.

```
[ElasticType(Name = "DataRecord")]
public class DataRecord : DocumentMapping
{
  [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
  public string HistoryId { get; set; }

  [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
  public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

  [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
  public List<ChannelValues> ChannelsValues { get; set; }
}
```

**How about if I want to change the number of properties of this class and the  and their name in the run time**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744742/index-a-dynamic-object-using-nest ?

Comment: Thanks for that. However, there problem with answer is that with dynamic class, how can we specify the property name variable each time? You can specify a property but the name of property is hard coded (fixed)