# Index a dynamic object using NEST 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I Found this question [Index a dynamic object using NEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744742/index-a-dynamic-object-using-nest) from 2 years ago.

I basically have exactly the same question but using NEST 5.0 . The proposed sollution doesn't work annymore in the newest version.

- casting to object and then indexing, results in an elasticsearch document with no fields in the source tag
- the esClient.Raw.Index api is missing

Comment: Do you get misbehavior / error messages? Have you tryed something to fix it? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with dynamic types is similar in NEST 5.x as it was in NEST 1.x; some of the client API has changed a little in between these versions but the premise is still the same.

Here's an example

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

// delete the index if it already exists
if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex);

// create an anonymous type assigned to a dynamically typed variable
dynamic instance = new
{
    Name = "Russ",
    CompanyName = "Elastic",
    Date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
};

// cast the instance to object to index, explicitly
// specify the document type and index
var indexResponse = client.Index((object)instance, i => i
    .Type("my_type")
    .Index(defaultIndex)
);

// fetch the document just indexed
var getResponse = client.Get<dynamic>(indexResponse.Id, g => g
    .Type(indexResponse.Type)
    .Index(indexResponse.Index)
);
```

The request and response JSON for this look like

```
HEAD http://localhost:9200/default-index?pretty=true

Status: 200

------------------------------

DELETE http://localhost:9200/default-index?pretty=true

Status: 200
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}

------------------------------

PUT http://localhost:9200/default-index?pretty=true 
{}

Status: 200
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true
}

------------------------------

POST http://localhost:9200/default-index/my_type?pretty=true 
{
  "name": "Russ",
  "companyName": "Elastic",
  "date": "2017-03-11T04:03:53.0561954+00:00"
}

Status: 201
{
  "_index" : "default-index",
  "_type" : "my_type",
  "_id" : "AVq7iXhpc_F3ya7MTJiU",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}

------------------------------

GET http://localhost:9200/default-index/my_type/AVq7iXhpc_F3ya7MTJiU?pretty=true

Status: 200
{
  "_index" : "default-index",
  "_type" : "my_type",
  "_id" : "AVq7iXhpc_F3ya7MTJiU",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Russ",
    "companyName" : "Elastic",
    "date" : "2017-03-11T04:03:53.0561954+00:00"
  }
}

------------------------------
```

This demonstrates that the document is indexed as expected, and the original source document can be retrieved.

The low level client can be accessed on the high level client in NEST 2.x and 5.x through the `.LowLevel` property, so you can do something similar to the linked question with

```
dynamic instance = new
{
    Id = "id",
    Index = defaultIndex,
    Type = "my_type",
    Document = new
    {
        Name = "Russ",
        CompanyName = "Elastic",
        Date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    }
};

string documentJson = client.Serializer.SerializeToString((object)instance.Document);

var result = client.LowLevel.Index<string>(instance.Index, instance.Type, instance.Id, documentJson);
```

Comment: lots of grattitude